# How to optimize for-loop

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, optimization

I'm using for-loop to filter matches from opencv knnFlann matcher, but i would need to optimize it

**Code:**

```
def orb_calc_matches(matches, distance_range=0.65):
    good_matches = []
    queried_matches = []

    for i in range(len(matches)):
        if len(matches[i]) == 2:
            if ((matches[i][0].trainIdx not in queried_matches) and (matches[i][0].distance < distance_range * matches[i][1].distance)):
                good_matches.append(matches[i][0])
                queried_matches.append(matches[i][0].trainIdx)
    return good_matches
```

can sombody propose, some more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe better posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make `queried_matches` a `set`. And use `for m in matches:` rather than a indexed loop as the indexes aren't needed.

```
def orb_calc_matches(matches, distance_range=0.65):
    good_matches = []
    queried_matches = set()

    for m in matches:
        if len(m) == 2:
            if ((m[0].trainIdx not in queried_matches) and
                (m[0].distance < distance_range * m[1].distance)):
                good_matches.append(m[0])
                queried_matches.add(m[0].trainIdx)
    return good_matches
```

Comment: It works, and it is a bit faster, but not significant difference..  My whole script got faster from 18.65 to 18,22sek
do you think it would be good thing to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to search in parellal?

Comment: I would look at reducing the number of matches before it gets to this function. It might be faster to sort matches or have matches sorted on `[0].trainIdx` and then `queried_matches` would just be an index and the test would be `m[0].trainIdx > queried_matches`.